# Why the inductor size increases even when the value of the inductor is same

Tags: inductor

Why there is Different case style size for the same inductor value

Comment: Why are the AA, C, and D batteries that have the same voltage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you wonder only about inductors?
Why are there capacitors of different size although they have the same capacitance value?

Main reasons:

- different **max. voltage** which requires more **distance** between "plates" (or different dielectric material; and that will have different dielectric constant)
- different **max. operation frequency** which requires different **dielectric material**

It's similar with inductors:

- different **max. current** which requires different **wire diameter** and/or different core material (because of saturation)
- different **max. operating frequency** which requires different **core material** (and that will have different permeablity constant)

Answer (score 7):

*Think* about it.  Why would you NOT expect that a 100 µH inductor that can handle 10 A would be bigger than one that can only handle 500 mA?

Ultimately, the physical size of a inductor is related to the energy it can store.  Different core materials can store different amounts of magnetic energy per volume, but within the same core material, inductor size is largely dictated by energy storage.

The energy a inductor can store, in common units, is:

J = ½ A<sup>2</sup>H

where J is the energy in Joules, A the current thru the inductor in Amps, and H the inductance in Henrys.

Look at a family of inductors that all use the same core, and you will see that the maximum energy storage is about the same across the family.  For example, here are the specs for the CoilCraft MSS6132 series of power inductors:

[image]

Pick a few and compute their energy storage at the 10% drop saturation level.  For example:

(4.7 µH)(2.18 A)<sup>2</sup>/2 = 11.2 µJ
  (8.2 µH)(1.78 A)<sup>2</sup>/2 = 13.0 µJ
  (22 µH)(970 mA)<sup>2</sup>/2 = 10.3 µJ
  (100 µH)(450 mA)<sup>2</sup>/2 = 10.1 µJ

So yes, size matters.

Answer (score 1):

Olin's answer here is a good one but to try to add of the physics behind this.

Inductance is given by the following formula:

$$L = N^2 \cdot \dfrac{\mu \cdot A_e}{l}$$

Where \$ L \$ is the inductance in henries, \$ N \$ is the number of turns, \$A_e\$ is effective area in square meters, \$ l \$ is length in meters and \$\mu\$ is the permittivity of the magnetic material ( \$ 4 \cdot \pi \cdot 10^{-7} \dot H \cdot m^{-1} \$ for free space).

\$ \mu \$ is related to the type of core used and its B-H curve. B is the flux density measured in Tesla and H is magnetising force measured in ampere-turns per meter.

Typical B-H Curves \$ \mu \$ is related to the slope of the curve at the point of interest.

[image]

As you can see different materials have different B-H curves and you may be asking your self why we don't just use one type of material.  The answer here is it depends on what you want it for.

You may just want something to smooth out a current waveform in which case you may not care if the inductance falls a bit with high current, a typical example here is the inductor in a Buck Converter. For this you want a core with a small coercive force to minimise losses but don't mind \$ \mu \$ reducing as the current increases - iron powder cores are a typical example.

You may not actually care about inductance at all but want to attenuate RF noise, for this you want something with a large coercive force to absorb the energy.  This is the principle behind ferrite beads.

You may want a particular inductance that remains constant over a wide current range. The best thing for this is air as it has a perfectly straight B-H curve. However for air \$ \mu \$ is relatively small so for this type of inductor people usually use a magnetic core but introduce a small known air gap to dominate the shape of the B-H curve.

Two more concerns are frequency and saturation and frequency some materials have higher saturation flux densities than others and others are better or worse at high frequencies.  If I was designing a 50 or 60Hz transformer I would probably have an iron core as the saturation B is relatively high so I can use less turns. For a 100kHz transformer in a SMPS the high frequency losses from iron would be excessive so I would probably go with a ferrite core but then I have to insure that maximum B is lower to avoid saturation.

Finally we get to the windings at higher current we need thicker wires and so need a bigger core to fit the turns into. Between any two turns in a winding there is capacitance because a capacitor is just two conductive plates separated by insulation. At HF this can dominate the inductance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, something else about the inductor changes as the case gets bigger:

- Lower DC resistance
- Higher self resonance frequency
- Cheaper
- Compatible with older parts

Answer (score 0):

Value of inductance depends of physical size of inductor, permeability of the core material and number of turns of wire.